What is the maximum supported compatibility level for EF6?
I'm in the process of migrating old .NET Framework & EF 6 Web API to .NET 8 and EF Core 8.
Yesterday because of this breaking change, I changed compatibility_level to 130 for our Azure SQL databases: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-8.0/breaking-changes#contains-in-linq-queries-may-stop-working-on-older-sql-server-versions
My question is: what is the recommended compatibility_level for EF6 and for EF Core 8?
We want to have the same database working for both EF6 and EF Core 8 because of migration testing.
EDIT after resolving: this is remarks for Azure SQL in Microsoft's documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-database-transact-sql-compatibility-level?view=sql-server-ver16&redirectedfrom=MSDN#remarks-for-azure-sql

Why did you change the compatibility level at all? Azure SQL isn't using unsupported database versions. The recommendation is to not change the compatibility level without understanding why

Seriously, what's the question here? You link to an article that doesn't refer to your database. If you use supported database versions, you shouldn't have to change anything. The article you linked to is only relevant if you want to use EF Core 8 with unsupported databases

EF6 WebAPI to .NET 8 and EF8 that's a far bigger change than you realize though. You're moving from EF Classic 6 to EF Core 8. The document you really need is Port from EF6 to EF Core  EF Core was a complete redesign and has some significant differences with EF Classic. The SQL Server compatibility level isn't an issue. The real problem will be missing methods, or things that work differently, or require different coding in EF Core

@PanagiotisKanavos i'm guessing he's running sql server that doesn't support OPENJSON and wants to use it for both EF6 and EF8, but he mentions azure, so i dunno :D OP, what' does: select @@version return?

@siggemannen yes, there's a lot of confusion here and the potential to cause damage due to unnecessary changes

EF and EF Core don't have any compatibility level - that's a thing of the underlying SQL Server database only.

As posted by EFCore Team member, it is safe to use latest compatibility level for Azure SQL: https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/33980#issuecomment-2165072564
I updated to 160 - no issues on both EF6 and EF8 WebAPIs yet.
